# Creating stored procedure in sql using the given date and emails

Tags: sql-server, email

I am setting up job schedule for sending notifications using the email addresses present in my table where their active flag is set to true. This notification will be sent every 24 hours.

In my table, I have this:

```
Email ID    Request ID     Receiver             Date Created  Email Flag
 1            2           receiver1@domain.com   9/10/2015        1
 2            4           receiver2@domain.com   9/11/2015        1   
 3            5           receiver3@domain.com   9/15/2015        1
```

This time, the email should be sent 24 hours from the date it was created and the email flag should be true.
I would like to ask for the basic algorithm that would serve as my guide to make the stored procedure for this one?

I set up my first code:

I just typed this in plain text so I don't know if some syntax is wrong.

```
USE [databasename]
GO


Declare 

@recipients AS VARCHAR(100)
@subject AS VARCHAR(200)
@body AS VARCHAR(200)
@s_date AS DateTime
@flag

select email_isactive from dbo.emails AS @flag where dbo.email_isactive == 1

if(flag == 1)

BEGIN

  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

   @recipients = 'Select email_receiver from dbo.rms_emails where dbo.is_active ==1'
   @subject = "Referral Monitoring Notification: For Approval"
   @body = "This serves as a notification that there's a regularization entry pending for your approval.
    Kindly visit http:// for more details. Thanks."
```

I haven't finished my code. I was stuck in the recipients portion since there are a lot of emails that will be used in the recipients. And also I have to consider the date if where should I put it and check if the current date is in 24 hours already from the date it was created.

I really need your assistance. I'm a little bit confused.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i think you are using `== 1` it seems `Incorrect Syntax`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are different systems.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, SQL Server Sir

Comment: @tinka, I'm sorry, I just wrote it in plain text.

Answer (score 2):

There's several syntax errors in there, and no logic. I'd consider learning more about SQL before asking questions, however here's some sample code to study, even if it will fail because you're not storing dates as a `DATETIME` format, which you should be, it's a good start:

```
DECLARE @RECIPIENTS NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @FLAG BIT
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
DECLARE @ID INT

SET @ID = 1

WHILE @ID <= (SELECT MAX([EMAIL ID] FROM DBO.EMAILS)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @RECIPIENTS = RECEIVER FROM DBO.EMAILS WHERE @ID = [EMAIL ID]
        SELECT @FLAG = [EMAIL FLAG] FROM DBO.EMAILS WHERE @ID = [EMAIL ID]
        SELECT @DATE = [DATE CREATED] FROM DBO.EMAILS WHERE @ID = [EMAIL ID]

        IF (@FLAG = 1 AND DATEDIFF(HH,@DATE,GETDATE()) >= 24)
            BEGIN
                EXEC MSDB.DBO.SP_SEND_DBMAIL
                @PROFILE_NAME = 'YOUR_DBMAIL_PROFILE'
                ,@RECIPIENTS = @RECIPIENTS
                ,@BODY = 'This serves as a notification that there''s a regularization entry pending for your approval. Kindly visit http:// for more details. Thanks.'
                ,@SUBJECT = 'Referral Monitoring Notification: For Approval'
            END

        SET @ID = @ID + 1
    END
```

Comment: than you so much for this one! It really a great help to start the procedure. Thank you again.

Comment: I like to know why it should be >= 24?

Comment: Because you'd like to send the email if the difference in hours is *more or equal to* 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

what i have noticed that you are using `dbo.email_isactive` it should be `dbo.emails.email_isactive` syntax: `schema.table.column`

```
select email_isactive from dbo.emails AS @flag where dbo.email_isactive == 1
```

it should be

```
select email_isactive from dbo.emails AS @flag where email_isactive = 1
```

second

```
@recipients = 'Select email_receiver from dbo.rms_emails where dbo.is_active ==1'
```

should be

```
@recipients = 'Select email_receiver from dbo.rms_emails where is_active =1'
```

and in this query you will get only top record of table based on your condition

if you want to select multiple mail within one variable with comma seperated

```
select STUFF((Select ','+email_receiver from dbo.rms_emails where is_active =1 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

Comment: so if I'm going to use the query for the recipients, does it mean that I could fetch up all the emails where flag is true regardless of the date it was created? How could I set that it will be sent using the recipients emails once it's 24 hours already?

Comment: @user4656677 so what you want you want all the mail in one variable with comma seperated

Comment: @user4656677 try `select 
STUFF((Select ','+email_receiver
from dbo.rms_emails
 where is_active =1
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')`